# Text moves when clicked on dropdown navigation bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, navigationbar

When I hover over my navigation bar and the dropdown menu (from the navigation bar) expands, the text below my navigation bar moves downwards. When move away from my navigation bar (stop hovering it), the text stands on the place where it should be.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v12/w8gdH283Tvk__Lua32TysjIfp8uK.ttf) format('truetype');
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --accent-color: #45494E;
  --gradient-color: #FBFBFB;
}
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:focus:after {
  width: 50px;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  background: #FBFBFB;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
body {
  background: #FFF; /* Achtergrondkleur pagina */
  font-family: "Varela Round", Nunito, Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  margin: 15px;
}
.menu > ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ol > li {
  background: rgb(121, 121, 121); /* Actergrond menu */
  border-left: 5px solid var(--gradient-color);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(1) {
  --accent-color: #FDA085;
  --gradient-color: #F6D365;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(2) {
  --accent-color: #BFF098;
  --gradient-color: #6FD6FF;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(3) {
  --accent-color: #EA8D8D;
  --gradient-color: #A890FE;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(4) {
  --accent-color: #D8B5FF;
  --gradient-color: #1EAE98;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(5) {
  --accent-color: #C6EA8D;
  --gradient-color: #FE90AF;
}
.menu > ol > li a {
  color: #FBFBFB;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within,
.menu > ol > li:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus:after,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within:after,
.menu > ol > li:hover:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
  max-width: 800px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus a:before,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within a:before {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.menu > ol > li:after {
  background: rgb(121, 121, 121); /* Achtergrond menu bij het uitfaden als aangewezen (hetzelfde als achtergrondkleur menu)*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid #FBFBFB;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:after {
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 1px;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:hover:after,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus:after {
  width: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  a:focus,
  a:hover {
    position: relative;
  }
  a:focus:after,
  a:hover:after {
    width: 50px;
  }
  a:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menu {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10vh; /* De ruimte tussen het menu en de bovenkant */
  }
  .menu > ol {
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu > ol > li {
    border-top: 5px solid var(--accent-color);
    border-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    right: -15px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
    max-height: 750px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 12.5px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover a:before {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  .menu > ol .sub-menu {
    border-left: 0;
    margin: 15px -15px -15px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  .menu > ol > li {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 25px;
  }
}

p {
  display: 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon.png"/>
    <title>Rune's smart home</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/solid.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./navbar.css">
  </head>
  <body id="everything">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
          <ol class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
          <ol class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>

    <p>This is the home page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I've posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it sweet and simple. Just add **height: 56px;** in **.menu** class in CSS. Will resolve your issue. Thanks

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v12/w8gdH283Tvk__Lua32TysjIfp8uK.ttf) format('truetype');
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
  --accent-color: #45494E;
  --gradient-color: #FBFBFB;
}
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:focus:after {
  width: 50px;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  background: #FBFBFB;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
body {
  background: #FFF; /* Achtergrondkleur pagina */
  font-family: "Varela Round", Nunito, Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  margin: 15px;
  height: 56px;
}
.menu > ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ol > li {
  background: rgb(121, 121, 121); /* Actergrond menu */
  border-left: 5px solid var(--gradient-color);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(1) {
  --accent-color: #FDA085;
  --gradient-color: #F6D365;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(2) {
  --accent-color: #BFF098;
  --gradient-color: #6FD6FF;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(3) {
  --accent-color: #EA8D8D;
  --gradient-color: #A890FE;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(4) {
  --accent-color: #D8B5FF;
  --gradient-color: #1EAE98;
}
.menu > ol > li:nth-child(5) {
  --accent-color: #C6EA8D;
  --gradient-color: #FE90AF;
}
.menu > ol > li a {
  color: #FBFBFB;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within,
.menu > ol > li:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus:after,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within:after,
.menu > ol > li:hover:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
  max-width: 800px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
}
.menu > ol > li:focus a:before,
.menu > ol > li:focus-within a:before {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.menu > ol > li:after {
  background: rgb(121, 121, 121); /* Achtergrond menu bij het uitfaden als aangewezen (hetzelfde als achtergrondkleur menu)*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid #FBFBFB;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li:hover,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus {
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:after {
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 1px;
}
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:hover:after,
.menu > ol .sub-menu li a:focus:after {
  width: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  a:focus,
  a:hover {
    position: relative;
  }
  a:focus:after,
  a:hover:after {
    width: 50px;
  }
  a:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menu {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10vh; /* De ruimte tussen het menu en de bovenkant */
  }
  .menu > ol {
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu > ol > li {
    border-top: 5px solid var(--accent-color);
    border-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus:after,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--accent-color), var(--gradient-color));
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    right: -15px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus .sub-menu,
  .menu > ol > li:focus-within .sub-menu {
    max-height: 750px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 12.5px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li:hover a:before {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  .menu > ol .sub-menu {
    border-left: 0;
    margin: 15px -15px -15px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  .menu > ol > li {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .menu > ol > li a:not(:last-child):before {
    right: 25px;
  }
}

p {
  display: 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon.png"/>
    <title>Rune's smart home</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/solid.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./navbar.css">
  </head>
  <body id="everything">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
          <ol class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Big Widgets</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Bigger Widgets</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Widgets</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#0">Kabobs</a>
          <ol class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Shishkabobs</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">BBQ kabobs</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Summer kabobs</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>

    <p>This is the home page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yeah great solution I was thinking the problem was coming from the positions of the dropdowns. Also I think it's "height: 55px" for this one @Rune

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using css framework then I suggest you to do so, because it greatly reduces your code and will definitely make your web page look decent.

You can use Bootstrap 4 and the navigation bar can be designed as given in this link:
[Navigation Bar with dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h)

This is the most cleanest code for navigation you can get.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RohanRao Using a framework isn't the all mighty solution, it cost in perfomance and peoples that don't use it can't help you with it, I think using pure css or things like scss is better for a lot of little scale apps/websites. Furthermore you don't help him to resolve his problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your ".submenu" in relative position so it affects your page flow.

```css
.menu > ol .sub-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid #FBFBFB;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 7.5px;
  position: relative; /* Use absolute position to avoid page flow conflicts */
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here you'll need some reformating but use the absolute position to avoid those things to happen.

Also your code is so hard to read because of all the inheritance you use, try to minimize your code using appropriate classes. You don't need to chain all your elements.

Hope it can help you, ask more if you need.

Comment: Hi, that doesn't fix the problem. If I do that, the background for the dropdown menu has disapeared...

Comment: @Rune I said you'll need some reformating because your submenu display will not act as before when in absolute position.